# Ubuntu additional drivers | amd64-microcode

Tags: 16.04, 15.04, 17.04, amd-processor, microcode

In **Software & Updates | Additional Drivers** (where I select the AMD graphics drivers) I see a new entry:

```
Unknown:Unknown
This device is not working.
```

With two options:

```
[ ] Using Processor microcode firmware for AMD CPUs from amd64-microcode (proprietary)
[*] Do not use the device
```

Is the "device is not working" line saying don't enable this option because it doesn't work anyway or maybe you should enable it because the (cpu) device is not working correctly?

Comment: See this - http://askubuntu.com/questions/613579/unknown-additional-driver-processor-microcode-firmware-for-intel-cpus-for-intel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your CPU is working fine. This just lets you download a later microcode and update it; this microcode for the CPU is proprietary so it shows up in the dialog for drivers.

There *is* an actual bug here but it is that this program produces a false alarm that implies your cpu is not working. [Here's the bug on Launchpad (1444682)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1444682).

Your CPU is probably fine either with or without it but it is the text in the GUI dialog is raising a false alarm that is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be the option to enable the amd64-microcode firmware for the processor. Not sure why it shows the device as unknown, looks like a bug. I had the same issue, then I installed amd64-microcode from the command line, and now the option "Using Processor microcode firmware for AMD CPUs from amd64-microcode (proprietary)" is selected in Additional Drivers. This appears to be a new feature to be able to enable this processor firmware from the Additional Drivers menu, but looks like a bug in the displayed name of the CPU as a device??

Answer (score 2):

Hi What are your computer specs? Check them [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download).

I have same problem but I've installed by drivers and have the software, so not sure if its video related?

I also have the same problem above,

Does anyone know what this is?

I done the following to install AMD Graphic drivers

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates xvba-va-driver libva-glx1 libva-egl1 vainfo
sudo amdconfig --initial
```

Followed by a reboot then `fglrxinfo` - and the info came back correct.

Just no idea what this other driver can be? (amd 7850k) is the processor I use,it does say its 8 core graphics, would I need to run `sudo amdconfig --adapter=all --initial`

Comment: My guess it is nothing to do with the graphics driver but more to do with the processor which is my case is an amd athlon II x4 640. Graphics are working fine for me. I've had the system hang a few times however I've been on beta for over a month so I wasn't overly concerned.

Comment: I've just installed sudo apt-get install hardinfo (device manager) but all seems okay - it is all working fine, it's just a pain because I know its there ><