# Unknown Additional Driver: Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs for intel-microcode

Tags: drivers, 15.04

After upgrading to 15.04, I have one additional driver (it did not appear in 14.10). What is the purpose of this driver and should I enable it?

[image]

Comment: Is there an Intel cpu? http://blog.surgut.co.uk/2015/03/intel-cpu-microcode-support-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The microcode data file for Linux contains the latest microcode
definitions for all Intel processors.

Intel releases microcode updates to correct processor behavior as documented in the respective processor specification updates.

While the regular approach to getting this microcode update is via a BIOS upgrade, Intel realizes that this is an administrative hassle.

The Linux Operating System has a mechanism to update the microcode after  booting the OS.

In Ubuntu Vivid Vervet 15.04,ubuntu-drivers-common is a framework to detect hardware-dependent components on user's machine.

## [Source](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/intel-microcode)

Comment: so, no to worry if this driver is not used?

Comment: Yes, no to worry if this driver is not used.

Comment: The link you provided is not a direct link to the information you're referring to. Do you mind correcting this?

Comment: @RolandiXor: updated!

Comment: I will add the the 'Do not use the device' doesn't mean you are not using the device, I think it means you aren't using it with the available proprietary driver. (e.g. my wifi card is set to 'do not use' in additional drivers but is happily using `bcma-pci-bridge` instead of the proprietary `wl`)

Comment: So this will permanently upgrade the BIOS?

Comment: @Flimm No, the update has to be reapplied. If you put "Do not use the device" the microcode will be the BIOS's not your Ubuntu's.

Comment: Will it speed up the system a little bit?

Comment: 56 upvotes on an answer I don't understand... :( In contrast, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331060/30271), for example, has a much clearer message.