# Ubuntu 15.04 and integrated Intel video

Tags: 15.04, intel-graphics, intel

I have Gigabyte b75m-d3h rev1.1(1155) with Corei3 2340(3.4ghz).
How do i get some video driver working?
this is how it looks like.
http://dox.bg/files/dw?a=e8255ecb14
[image]

Comment: what is the problem ? you have a video driver working.

Comment: im used to consider UNKNOWN for "NOT WORKING WELL"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already using a video driver. If you didn't have a video driver working you wouldn't see anything on your monitor. What your screenshot is showing us is that you have another piece of hardware that ubuntu doesn't recognize the vendor but as I can understand from your screenshot the (unrecognized) device is working with its proprietary driver, which is recommended the most of times.

Comment: So i can still use the even small potential?

Comment: I think this answer details about your unknown driver: http://askubuntu.com/questions/613579/unknown-additional-driver-processor-microcode-firmware-for-intel-cpus-for-intel. So yeah, there is no problem with it.

Comment: You're welcome and enjoy your ubuntu SO ;) don't forget to mark my answer as correct if you like it.