# Should I activate the additional driver: Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs for intel-microcode

Tags: drivers, intel, cpu

I have recently noticed that there is an additional driver called `Unknown: Unknown` here which was not there before:

[image: Additional Drivers sudden odd appearance]

I have already read [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/613624/364819), and understand why it is there, but my question is, should I activate it? Will this make a difference? Or should I just leave it as it is as it sounds rather useful?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

Comment: I will add the the 'Do not use the device' doesn't mean you are not using the device, I think it means you aren't using it with the available proprietary driver.

Comment: Yes I have activated intel micro codec for my Compaq Presario C700 with core 2 duo T4300. After the change I lost my menus and could not use the system. I retested the same going through new installation. Result was the same. At least in this case activation of cpu microcodecs force me to keep away from Ubuntu 16.04. So be careful if you activate the cpu micro codecs.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I suggest activating the driver. There is no potential harm at all.

This driver updates CPU microcode.

If microcode in bios is older than in Ubuntu, it will be updated.

But do not expect any noticeable change.

You can read [this](https://wiki.debian.org/Microcode) for clarification.