# What is the difference between using intel-microcode and not using it?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, intel, gpu-driver

What are the effects and implications of choosing one of the following two options over the other?

- Performance differences?
- Stability differences?
- Which of the two is better supported long-term?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks @karel! What I take from this is that it's better to not use intel-microcode as it is not necessary and can reduce performance.

Comment: This is wrong. It is better to use microcode.

Comment: @Pilot6 why is it better to use microcode?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/648019/should-i-activate-the-additional-driver-processor-microcode-firmware-for-intel/648025?s=2|3.0653#648025

Comment: Microcode fixes CPU errors. It is loaded anyway from BIOS. If there is a newer version available, intel-microcode loads a newer one.