# Kernel outputting this, should I worry? - [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406e3 TIME 1498209621 SOCKET 0 APIC 3 microcode 9e

Tags: kernel, cpu, overheating, temperature

I have dmesg -Hw running trying to troubleshoot other problem (my ssd ocasionally going in read-only mode) and noticed this that happens few times per day, should I worry

```
[  +0,000010] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 3: Machine Check: 0 Bank 128: 0000000088132802
[  +0,000003] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 73c18f80472d 
[  +0,000002] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406e3 TIME 1498206112 SOCKET 0 APIC 3 microcode 9e
[  +0,000002] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 1: Machine Check: 0 Bank 128: 0000000088132802
[  +0,000001] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 73c18f806082 
[  +0,000002] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406e3 TIME 1498206112 SOCKET 0 APIC 2 microcode 9e
[юни23 12:20] CPU1: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 50362)
[  +0,000001] CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 50362)
[  +0,000002] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 55265)
[  +0,000001] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 55265)
[  +0,000002] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 55310)
[  +0,000004] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 55310)
[  +0,000011] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 3: Machine Check: 0 Bank 128: 0000000088122803
[  +0,000002] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 7cb77a5d573c 
[  +0,000002] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406e3 TIME 1498209621 SOCKET 0 APIC 3 microcode 9e
[  +0,000003] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 1: Machine Check: 0 Bank 128: 0000000088122803
[  +0,000001] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 7cb77a5da526 
[  +0,000001] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406e3 TIME 1498209621 SOCKET 0 APIC 2 microcode 9e
[  +0,000960] CPU3: Core temperature/speed normal
[  +0,000000] CPU1: Core temperature/speed normal
[  +0,000001] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[  +0,000001] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[  +0,000001] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[  +0,000001] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[  +0,000006] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 1: Machine Check: 0 Bank 128: 0000000088132802
[  +0,000002] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 7cb77a87b4ec 
[  +0,000005] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406e3 TIME 1498209621 SOCKET 0 APIC 2 microcode 9e
[  +0,000003] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 3: Machine Check: 0 Bank 128: 0000000088132802
[  +0,000001] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 7cb77a87d40c 
[  +0,000003] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406e3 TIME 1498209621 SOCKET 0 APIC 3 microcode 9e
```

Answer (score 2):

Google search of "[Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406e3 TIME 1498209621 SOCKET 0 APIC 3 microcode 9e" gives the following:

Several things to try:

- Install microcode. ([askubuntu.com: installing microcode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648019/should-i-activate-the-additional-driver-processor-microcode-firmware-for-intel))
- Check if the computer is overheating with `lm-sensors` ([ubuntu.com: sensors howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto))
- bad irq settings in bios ([hardware error cpu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2098028))
- Someone mentioned bad power supply unit (psu) and machine check exception (mce) for hard drive in intel forum ([linux machine check exception](https://communities.intel.com/thread/51172))
- Overheating can cause that error ([prime number calculation overheating](http://mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?p=455234))