# Lubuntu install to replace XP fails with hardware errors

Tags: boot, system-installation, lubuntu, hardware

I wanted to install a new OS onto an old XP computer I found in a garage sale. This isn't dual booting, I want Linux to to be the main OS on this system.

I burnt Lubuntu onto a 4.7 GB DvD and and attempted to install it onto an old and blank 60GB hard drive by starting up the OS. At first it seemed to work, Lubuntu logo showed and did the loading animation, select language, memory test was fine, disc check was fine, but I get a problem when trying to run the actual OS.
It's a black screen with:

```
     0.036033] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 0: a200000010
 0080f
     0.036033] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0
     0.036033] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:f49 TIME 1009843292 SOCKET 0 A
 IC 0 microcode 3
     121.664613] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0 flags 0
     133.928675] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0 flags 0
```

or just:

```
     123.796324] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0 flags 0
     136.076077] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0 flags 0
```

Both allowing me to use the mouse, but not the keyboard.

I don't know what could have possibly gone wrong, Windows XP works fine on that thing, and it can clearly recognize the processor model and use it.

Comment: We will need to know the computer model and which Lubuntu you are trying use to be of help.  If you can give cpu and graphics type, someone can help better.

Comment: Can check this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/928390/kernel-outputting-this-should-i-worry-hardware-error-processor-0406e3-ti

Comment: Did you use the 32-bit Lubuntu 18.04.3 ISO from https://lubuntu.me/downloads/ ? Please click [edit] and advise.

Comment: Ok, I tried to install 32 bit Lubuntu, but I'm presented with a blank, light blue screen with something that resembles a task bar. Nothing seems to happen when I try to install it.