# Ubuntu 16.04LTS freezes

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

I recently upgraded my motherboard, processor, ram and psu.

- Motherboard - Asus Prime B250-Pro - LGA1151 - 7th Generation MotherBoard (LGA1151, DDR4 Upto 64GB 2400MHz, Dual M.2, Intel Optane Ready)
- RAM - ADATA Premier ADT DDR4 U-DIMM 2400 8GB RAM X 2
- PSU - Corsair VS550 550-Watt Power Supply
- Processor - Intel® Core™ i5-7400 CPU @ 3.00GHz × 4

System details looks like this -

[image]

The HDD remained the same after the migration.

Now, randomly and quite frequently, the screen goes weired and looks like this - 
[image]

After this, nothing works except a hard shutdown and reboot.

What could be going wrong? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like a graphic card issue, did you install any drivers? Can you go to tty when freeze happens? Try CTRL-ALT-F2,F3,F4. CTRL-ALT-F7 returns you back to graphical interface.

Comment: I haven't installed any new drivers yet after the hardware upgrade. I thought I'd be asked by the system to do it. Am I wrong?
I can't go to tty when the freeze happens. Thanks. @MustafaYılmaz

Comment: You might need to install graphics driver, this image shows the onboard card. Do you have another graphics card? If so try to install its drivers. Basic google search helps a lot

Comment: Thanks. I don't have an additional graphics driver. Just checked the 'Additional Drivers' and there was an unknown device. Opted to use the 'intel-microcode' driver for the same. Lets see if it happens again. Any idea what that device might me?

Comment: Look here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/648019/should-i-activate-the-additional-driver-processor-microcode-firmware-for-intel

Comment: The freeze still occurs. Any clues?