# Ubuntu 15.10 driver AMD A10-5750M

Tags: drivers, 15.10, gpu, gpu-driver

I opened additional drivers section and I can see that I have something that  I don't understand. Can you help me what would you select if you have CPU AMD A10-5750M with built in graphic card. I am using ubuntu 15.10

[image]

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/613579/unknown-additional-driver-processor-microcode-firmware-for-intel-cpus-for-intel (same applies for AMD CPU)

Answer (score 0):

> what would you select

The one that works. Plain and simple.

If something works for you why would you go looking for alternatives?

Comment: Yea but I don't know what is this second device. Does somebody know that?

Comment: ah that one :) see the comment I made