# What is this "unknown device" in my "Additional Drivers"?

Tags: drivers, graphics, hardware, additional-drivers

I opened *Software&Updates > Additional Drivers* as I'm looking into some GPU issues, and was surprised to find an "unknown" device listed. I've never encountered that before, but I haven't modified my hardware in a long time.

I have no idea how long this unknown device has been here, or what it might be.

--> How can I determine what this extra device might be?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a device actually.

This is the option to install CPU microcode updater. CPU microcode is loaded by bios, but if you want Ubuntu to install a later version, if any exists, you can turn on this option.

Comment: Thank you! I have absolutely no idea what this means but I did understand  [from here](http://askubuntu.com/a/613624/5786) that it's safe to enable and even appears to be a good idea. So I'll do that - thanks!