# What is this device in "additional drivers"?

Tags: drivers, 15.10, additional-drivers

What is this unknown device?  It defaulted to "do not use this device" and said "this device is not working".  I had to choose the proprietary option and now it says "This device is using an alternative driver".

[image]

Comment: You can find your answer here. http://askubuntu.com/questions/613579/unknown-additional-driver-processor-microcode-firmware-for-intel-cpus-for-intel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25512/Linux-Processor-Microcode-Data-File) :

> The microcode data file contains the latest microcode definitions for all Intel® processors. Intel releases microcode updates to correct processor behavior as documented in the respective processor specification updates. While the regular approach to getting this microcode update is via a BIOS upgrade, Intel realizes that this can be an administrative hassle. The Linux* operating system and VMware ESX* products have a mechanism to update the microcode after booting. For example, this file will be used by the operating system mechanism if the file is placed in the /etc/firmware directory of the Linux system.