# Identifying Device that is missing driver

Tags: drivers, 16.04

The screenshot below indicates an unknown device: as I understand it this also indicates the unknown device is missing its driver. Hardware is a HP Elitebook 8440P

Is there a command to identify the unknown device?

```
$ lshw | pastebinit
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

http://paste.ubuntu.com/17337705/

[image]

Comment: What device are you asking about?

Comment: There are no missing drivers there.

Comment: @MarkKirby But one of the devices is not using the driver?

Comment: @Tim This had me confused. You think they mean what the `unknown` device is for the micro code driver?

Comment: @MarkKirby I think what they want to know is "which device is not using the driver". (I.e. detect the device which is "not working".

Comment: @gatorback Can you explain *why* you want this command - why does the GUI not work?

Comment: A little off topic, but OK: I am interested in the  command because I would like to learn the command set to identify hardware.   I prefer performing command line diagnostics over GUIs.

Comment: Related: [Unknown Additional Driver: Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs for intel-microcode](http://askubuntu.com/questions/613579/unknown-additional-driver-processor-microcode-firmware-for-intel-cpus-for-intel)