# Why does Ubuntu list my Intel Graphics drivers as Unknown:Unknown (not recommended)?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I've a laptop with Intel Graphics 520 (Skylake 6500U) and Nvidia 940MX.

I've installed the proprietary Nvidia driver (375.66) and it works fine. Also, I can switch between Intel and Nvidia graphics through the Nvidia Control Panel.

But why does Ubuntu list the Intel Graphics driver as Unknown:Unknown and why is it not recommended like the Nvidia driver?

Why is it saying "This device is using an alternative driver."? How can I install and configure the Intel Graphics driver such that it is both recommended and listed as Intel?

The OS is Ubuntu 17.04 (x64) and it is fully updated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The system does not list your Intel graphics as "unknown".

What you see at that screen in Intel CPU microcode updater. It is not related to graphics.

See [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/613579/167850) for clarification.

There is no proprietary driver for Intel adapters. They are built into the system.

Everything is OK with your system, nothing to be done with graphics.

Comment: But why the Unknown:Unknown?

Comment: Because it is not a driver. They placed it here to install easily.

Comment: It's not a driver, it's firmware for the CPU with the latest optimizations for such chip from Intel. Ubuntu works without it but better to have it. That's why it's now activated by default, unlike the proprietary graphics drivers, if applicable.

Comment: @MichaelBay - the Intel firmware was actually disabled by default on my machine.